# Формат генератора списка в параметре функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в параметре метода `join` можно упускать квадратные скобки при генерации списка?

```py
my_str = ' '.join(i for i in ['rat','milk','pit','bull','dog'] if len(i)>3)
```

Но

```py
A = i for i in ['rat','milk','pit','bull','dog'] if len(i)>3
```

вызовет ошибку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выражение без квадратных скобок (`[]`) и с ними — это два разных выражения.

---

В Вашем примере Вы не используете квадратные скобки, поэтому следующее выражение:

```py
i for i in ['rat','milk','pit','bull','dog'] if len(i)>3
```

расценивается как ***генератор*** (`generator expression` или же `genexpr`).
Обычно такие выражения обрамляются в круглые скобки (`()`), но они иногда могут быть опущены, как в первом Вашем примере.

Если же квадратные скобки использовать:

```py
[i for i in ['rat','milk','pit','bull','dog'] if len(i)>3]
```

то это уже будет ***списковое включение*** (`list comprehension` или же `listcomp`).

---

Большой разницы между ними нет.
Если в кратце, то генератор возвращает значения по одному и только если его "попросить", а списковое включение сразу возвращает готовый список.

В Вашем примере эта разница неочевидна.
Всё потому, что метод `join` поддерживает методы итерирования и сам по одному "просит" элементы из генератора.

---

Теперь давайте докажем это, проведя дизассемблирование кода. Чтоб уж наверняка :)

***Генератор:***

```py
print(dis.dis(r"x = ' '.join(i for i in [1, 2, 3])"))
```

*stdout (частично):*

```py
4 LOAD_CONST 1 (<code object <genexpr> at ..., file "<dis>", line 1>)
#                             ^^^^^^^
```

***Списковое включение:***

```py
print(dis.dis(r"x = ' '.join([i for i in [1, 2, 3]])"))
```

*stdout (частично):*

```py
4 LOAD_CONST 1 (<code object <listcomp> at ..., file "<dis>", line 1>)
#                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Круглые скобки могут быть опущены в генераторном выражении, если это не создаёт неоднозначности. Проще говоря, когда оно используется в качестве единственного аргумента функции. На списковые и словарные включения это не распространяется.